# dynamically added input fields not submitting

Tags: javascript, input, mootools, submit

here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhiteRau/36yC5/).  i'm sorry if it doesn't work properly; damn things rarely do for me...  i hate jsFiddle, but it gets the code to you faster...

the php document it goes to simply does this:

```
<pre><?php
print_r($_POST);?>
</pre>
```

the rows add to the DOM just fine.  but the values do not submit to the $_POST array.

what am i missing?

and yes i've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386228/add-form-element-dynamically-using-javascript-not-submitting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898508/jquery-ajax-form-and-dynamically-created-form-elements-not-submitting) and they don't help.
using Mootools, btw, so please don't bother with any jQuery answers.

Comment: oddly enough, if i add these rows via an imported CSV file...they submit just fine.  WTH!?  WR!

Comment: the fiddle seems incomplete, getting syntax errors there.

Comment: i can never get the damn jsFiddle to work.  but the code is there... seemed easier than posting it all here...

Comment: As someone suggested you should post code here and as an addition place a link to jsFiddle. What's so hard in jsFiddle? You may wish to answer privately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code I see an HTML syntax error. Can you check this line:

```
<input class="catCell" name"catlist" id="catList" type="text" tabindex="345"
    value="none or name" onChange="markFilled('catList', this.value);">
```

The syntax error is on `name` attribute, that is essential to get form submission work...

Comment: YOU, my lad, are correct.  the script does not add a name attribute.  thank you.  i did not know it was key for form submissions.  i'll have to recheck the W3 docs on that.  thank you very very much.  :D

Comment: one small problem: setting the name programmatically isn't taking.  any idea why? `newRow.name="booyah";` is how i'm assigning it, but, like i said, it doesn't stick.  :(

Comment: @WhiteRau Looking at your first fiddle, `newRow` is a `<tr>` element. You have to give name to inputs, so (I think) you have to `newInput.name="booyah";`... And names must be different for every input, elsewhere you PHP script will see only the last one.

Comment: yeah.  i added a counter in there.  what the big problem turned out to be was that i had to use the `setAttribute` method instead of the dot syntax.  otherwise it just didn't seem to stick.  thank you!

Comment: "The syntax error is on name attribute, that is essential to get form submission work..."  - you have opened my eyes. bro! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Having your form element inside a table element can also be a cause of this issue

Comment: That's what was helpful in my case.

Comment: Also my case... legacy code...

Answer (score 0):

```
            $('nextStep').addEvent('click', function(e) {
                console.log('BAM! form intercepted!');
                $('clientDataForm').send();});
```

basicly all i did is add `});` to the end..
and amazingly, it works!

here:
http://jsfiddle.net/36yC5/9/

Comment: i'm thrilled that you got it to work there.  problem is, i yarded those lines out of a big domready function.  check my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhiteRau/36yC5/10/) again and you'll see what i mean.  my concern is that when it submits, the $_POST array doesn't contain the newly added rows...  something i can't setup in Fiddle... :P

Comment: from a test with the jsfiddle i posted, and fiddler, everything is posted as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these errors coming from the wrong structure of HTML.

Cases:
1. Form element start within the table OR Form close before the table end

```html
<table><form>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
</form></table>
```

This will not work

```html
<form><table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr></table></form>
```

This will work (Observe the form begin before the table and ends after the table)

2. Form start OR end inappropriate place
3. Not specifying "name" attributes