# Javascript Dynamic HTML Inputs to POST via PHP (Need to rename field's per added input)

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've seen a few questions that were similar but not specific enough. This one - [Submit form input fields added with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312605/submit-form-input-fields-added-with-javascript) - is the closest comparison, but it is overwhelming for me (not really a javascript guy).

I'm trying to have dynamically added inputs which post independently on the next page via PHP. My code is as follows (which I found off google).

**FORM PAGE**

```
<script language="javascript">
fields = 0;
function addInput() {
if (fields != 19) {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<li>Link Title:<br /><input type='text' name='title' /><br />Link Address:<br /><input type='text' name='name' /><br />Description:<br /><input type='text' name='copy' /></li>";
fields += 1;
} else {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />Only 20 data entries allowed.";
document.form.add.disabled=true;
}
}
</script>

<form name="form" action="form.php" method="post">
<ul class="form">
<li>
Link Title:<br /><input type="text" name="title" /><br />
Link Address:<br /><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Description:<br /><input type="text" name="copy" />
</li>
<div id="text">

</div>
</ul>
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add input field" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**POST PAGE** - Wasn't sure where to begin since all of the fields are using the name 'title'? - I'll be okay with this page though.

```
<?php

    echo $_POST['title'];

?>
```

Comment: try to name them like array, for example name="title[]" and then in php just try to print the data out, like print_r($_POST['title']), you will see the effect /edit you can also put the variable `fields` into the input name, but it will be harder to handle them after submitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
innerHTML += "<li>Link Title:<br /><input type='text' name='title' /><
```

If you change that last bit to

```
name='title" + fields + "' /><
```

(watch where the second apostrophe went) then they gain unique names of title0, title1, title2...

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work. When I try to echo the titles, they print the first input but have errors on the others "Notice: Undefined index: title2"

Comment: EDIT - Nevermind this does work, I just added it to the first input (not part of the javascript).