# Ho to add input box dynamically and submit the result on top / under the input boxes (NOT on alert box)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

May i note that i have no knowledge of php or javascript
Your input would be appreciated ... 
I have found a script to do what i need, except for the fact that the results are displayed in array. (the script can be found at the bottom of this question topic )

I would like for the script instead to display each input, one under another (and not as an array, nor as an alert box)

So if each input has value of: a; b; c; d
the result should be displayed on the page as:

```
a
b
c
d
```

and NOT as:

```
Array ( [poll] => Array ( [question] => a [option1] => b [option2] => c [option3] => d ) )
```

I will be managing about 100 inputs, so i need this to NOT be displayed as Alert Box, nor would i need it to be displayed as Array.
Below is the script that needs tweaking to suit my needs.

```
<?php
    print_r($_REQUEST)
?>
<html>
<body>

<form id="myForm" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="text" name="poll[question]"> 
    <input type="text" name="poll[option1]"> 
    <input type="text" name="poll[option2]"> 
</form> 
<a href="javascript:addOption();">Add option</a> 

<script> 
    var optionNumber = 3; //The first option to be added is number 3 
    function addOption() { 
        var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm"); 
        var newOption = document.createElement("input"); 
        newOption.name = "poll[option"+optionNumber+"]"; // poll[optionX]
        newOption.type = "text";
        theForm.appendChild(newOption); 
        optionNumber++;
    } 
</script>


<!-- 
reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312605/submit-form-input-fields-added-with-javascript
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of doing `print_r($_REQUEST)`, which is giving you the array, loop over `$_REQUEST` and output the data in a block level tag.

Comment: i'd like to add that i have no knowledge of php or javascript

Comment: Take a look at function array_values()